# Link param doesn't render in JSX (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

```
<Link to={{pathname:'/profile',query: {id: {user.id}}}>View </Link>
```

I want to render a link that go to a path, but in my dom I see `profile/user?user.id`

Early on I tried something more simple

```
<Link to="/profile/{user.id}">View </Link> it doesn't work too.
```

Comment: try <Link to={"/profile/" + user.id}>View </Link>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Link to={"/profile/" + user.id}>View </Link>
```

This is what you're looking for